# One single input attribute is turning into multiple attributes

Tags: php, html, input

I have an ajax call which returns a select with options filled with an sql query, I'm filling the options like this:

```
echo '<option value='.$row['cve_preparatoria'].' nombre='.$row['cve_preparatoria'].'>'.$row['nombre_preparatoria'].'</option>';
```

But this is creating multiple attributes instead of 1, for example:

```
<option value="07EBH0076V" nombre="ESCUELA" preparatoria="" agropecuaria="" del="" estado="" "belisario="" domÍnguez="" palencia"="">ESCUELA PREPARATORIA AGROPECUARIA DEL ESTADO "BELISARIO DOMÍNGUEZ PALENCIA"</option>
```

value is okay, but the attribute "nombre" should be just *ESCUELA PREPARATORIA AGROPECUARIA DEL ESTADO "BELISARIO DOMÍNGUEZ PALENCIA"*

UPDATE: I solved it, it was a problem with quotes.
This was my solution:

```
        echo "<option value='".$row['cve_preparatoria']."' nombre='".$row['nombre_preparatoria']."'>".$row['nombre_preparatoria']."</option>";
```

If you use double quotes for *echo*, you need to use single quotes for the attributes value.

Comment: Add quotes around/for your attributes

Comment: I do have both: value and name quoted, but the attribute name's value somehow is creating more attributes named with the value of name, creating select's option with multiple empty attributes.

Comment: @LuisVillegas please update the question with your clarifications with an [edit]. Please don't hide details in comments, which can be removed.